# Missing Puppet.conf

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

I'm configuring a puppet master server for the first time.

I've completed the Pre-install Tasks

I'm now working on the [post-install tasks](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/install_puppet/post_install.html)

The Puppet documentation indicates that before starting the Server, you should perform several edits to the puppet.conf file.  Again, [according to the documentation](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/dirs_confdir.html) that file should be located at /etc/puppet for OS X.

I can verify that the folder exists, but `puppet.conf` is not present.

Running `puppet config print` shows the following config directory:

```
confdir = /Users/tech/.puppet
```

(config print also confirms a multitude of pre-configured settings)

I can confirm that the conf file DOES NOT EXIST.

Where is it pulling these settings from and where should I edit puppet.conf?

Comment: What about if the `config print` is run as root?

Comment: run as root it it returns config = /etc/puppet/puppet.conf (No file currently exists there.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's using the right location for the file, but there's no file there, which means it's using defaults for all the settings at the moment.

Go ahead and create the file and populate it with the settings you need, it's INI format and probably most of the settings can go under a `[main]` section.